# migration did not run in terminal, but it did in database

Tags: postgresql, docker, typeorm

App in development, using Postgres, docker, and typeorm. Terminal shots error as if migration did not run,  and says "relation 'orphanages' already exist".

But my database client tool beekeper shows all migrations were created just fine, and api is receiving data normaly in all routes.

Anyone has any clue what s happening?

```
ormconfig.json
```

```js
  {
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "docker",
    "database": "happy",
    "synchronize": true,
    "migrations": [
      "./src/database/migrations/*.ts"
    ],
    "entities": [
      "./src/models/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
      "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
    }

  }
```

migration file:

```js
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table} from "typeorm";

export class Orphanage1616788509901 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
            name: 'orphanages',
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'uuid',
                    unsigned: true,
                    isPrimary: true,
                    isGenerated: true,
                
                },
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'varchar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'latitude',
                    type: 'varchar'        
                },
                {
                    name: 'longitude',
                    type: 'varchar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'about',
                    type: 'text'
                },
                {
                    name: 'instructions',
                    type: 'text'
                },
                {
                    name: 'opening_hours',
                    type: 'varchar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'open_on_weekends',
                    type: 'boolean',
                    default: 'false'
                },
                {
                    name: 'user_name',
                    type: 'varchar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'user_id',
                    type: 'uuid'
                }

            ],
            foreignKeys: [
                {
                    name: 'OrphanageUser',
                    columnNames: ['user_id'],
                    referencedTableName: 'users',
                    referencedColumnNames: ['id'],
                    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                }
            ]
        }))
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.dropTable('orphanages');
    }

}
```

entity file

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany, JoinColumn, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import Image from './Images';
import User from './User';

@Entity('orphanages')  
export default class Orphanage {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    latitude: string;

    @Column()
    longitude: string;

    @Column()
    about: string;

    @Column()
    instructions: string;

    @Column()
    opening_hours: string;

    @Column()
    open_on_weekends: boolean;

    @Column()
    user_id: number;

    @Column()
    user_name: string;   

    @OneToMany(() => Image, image => image.orphanage, {
    cascade: ['insert' , 'update']
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'orphanage_id'})  
    images: Image[];


    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.orphanages)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id'}) 
    user: User;


}
```

user migration file

```js
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table} from "typeorm";

export class User1616788592127 implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
            name: 'users',            
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'uuid',
                    unsigned: true,
                    isPrimary: true,
                    isGenerated: true,
                    // generationStrategy:'increment'
                    
                },
                {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'varchar'
                },
                {
                    name: 'email',
                    type: 'varchar',
                    isUnique: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'password',
                    type: 'varchar',
                },
                {
                    name: 'role',
                    type: 'varchar',
                },     
                {
                    name: "date",
                    type: "timestamp",
                },
                {
                    name: "isVerified",
                    type: "boolean",
                    default: false,
                },    
                {
                    name: "tokenId",
                    type: "uuid",
                    // default: false,
                }, 
            ],
            foreignKeys: [
                {
                    name: 'TokenUser',
                    columnNames: ['tokenId'],
                    referencedTableName: 'tokens',
                    referencedColumnNames: ['id'],
                    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                }
            ]

            
 
        }))
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.dropTable('users');
    }

}
```

user entity file

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, OneToMany, OneToOne, JoinColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, createConnection } from 'typeorm'; // decorators from typeorm
// import { Length, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import Orphanage from './Orphanage';
import Token from './Token';


@Entity('users') 
export default class User {
   
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column({
      unique: true
    })
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;
  
    @Column()
    role: string;
    default: 'basic'
    enum: ["basic", "supervisor", "admin"];



    @Column({
      type: "timestamp"
    })
    date!: Date;

    @Column({
      default: false
    })
    isVerified: boolean;

       
    checkIfUnencryptedPasswordIsValid(unencryptedPassword: string) {
      return bcrypt.compareSync(unencryptedPassword, this.password);
    }


    @OneToMany(() => Orphanage, orphanage => orphanage.user, {
        cascade: ['insert' , 'update']
    })     
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id'}) 
    orphanages: Orphanage[];

    @OneToOne(() => Token, token => token.user, {
      // cascade: ['insert' , 'update'] //
    }) 
    @JoinColumn({name: "tokenId"})
    // token: Token[];
    token: Token;
    


    
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo. If I look correctly you creates a table `users` and in your code `ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.orphanages` you want to assign `user`

Comment: According to documentation, "user.orphanage" represents the inverse relation in User entity:  '@OneToMany(() => Orphanage, orphanage => orphanage.user'. The way it is set up, migration run command was running fine in previous project with sqlite3